# ClassNotFoundException in Tomcat console when using jawr

Tags: java, servlets

I am using Tomcat from Eclipse. When i try to start the server I am getting the following error in the console:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.jawr.web.servlet.JawrServlet
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)

When i deploy the war file in the Tomcat server outside of eclipse it is not having any problems. I am only getting this problem when i am trying to start tomcat from eclipse with jawr. Please let me know the solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Jaya

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your jawr jar is not in your build path?

i.e. in plain Tomcat it's being loaded automatically from /WEB-INF/lib/, whereas Eclipse may be expecting it to be explicitly mapped.

Eclipse may be expecting it to be specifically added to the Build Path (in the Package Explorer, right-click on the Jar and "Add to build path", or on the project, right click Build Path > configure build path)

I think it's something like that. Hard to say for sure without more details ...